# Is it possible to use manifolds to transfer gas from one keg to another?

Tags: carbonation

I have a standard manifold much like this one
[image]

A while back I thought of equalizing the pressure in two of my kegs by opening their check valves on the manifold. To test whether this would work I first opened one check valve **1** which was attached to a keg that was over carbed. I then made sure check valve **2** was not attached to anything and then I opened it up.

No gas came out of **2**! Is this normal? Maybe I am wrong and I should attach a low pressure gauge to check valve **2** to actually read the pressure coming out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's normal operation for a check valve. They're designed to let gas flow only in one direction -- from the regulator to the keg. The #1 check valve will not allow gas to flow from the keg into the manifold, which is why no gas flowed from #2 valve.

Comment: Duh moment on my part. Didn't know they performed just like aquarium air pump "check valves".